# Receiving response from CURL in JAVA

Tags: java, json, http, curl, sentiment-analysis

I am using a public API provided by Sentiment-140 for finding whether a small text is positive, negative or neutral. Though I can successfully use their simple HTTP-JSON service, I'm failing with CURL. Here's my code :

```
public static void makeCURL(String jsonData) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {
    byte[] queryData = jsonData.getBytes("UTF-8");

    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.1", 8080));
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson").openConnection(proxy);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    InputStream instr = con.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instr));

    os.write(queryData);
    os.close();
    String lin;
    while((lin = br.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println("[Debug]"+lin); // I expect some response here But it's not showing anything            
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your proxy require authentication ? Any exception ? stacktrace ?

Comment: No authentication. I can successfully use the similar techniques for getting regular HTTP response...

Comment: Try moving these lines:     InputStream instr = con.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instr)); after the os.write() and os.close().

Comment: Moved the lines. Still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You should send all your request data before getting input stream of connection.

```
byte[] queryData = jsonData.getBytes("UTF-8");
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.1", 8080));
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson").openConnection(proxy);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write(queryData);
os.close();

InputStream instr = con.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instr));
String lin;
while((lin = br.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println("[Debug]"+lin);
}
```